# How to put flat rate before subtotal at checkout time in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, rate, flat

I want to put flat rate before subtotal which is by default below to subtotal.

Answer (score 0):

How to add an additional Fee or Discount, or any kind of charge to order total of the magento checkout process
In a typical order, the order totals usually comprises of Sub Total, Shipping Cost, Taxes, Discount, based on these values the total order grand total is calculated.
This extra fee which we are adding to the total would reflect in the

**Checkout Page Order Total,
Cart Page Order Total,
My Account Order View Page,
Print Order PDF,
Order EMails,
Admin Order View/Email/PDF,
Admin Invoice View/Email/PDF,
Admin Credit Memo View/Email/PDF.**

Checkout Page Total Order Total Basics
We will see how to add the totals only to the checkout page. All the totals line items that show up the checkout page come from files located at folder **Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Address\Total**.

In magento before order is placed all order data is stored in a quote object and after order is placed it gets transferred to the order object. The quote totals follow the collector pattern and we can add collector as many collector classes. To add collector to the quote object in our config.xml we add the lines

```
<global>
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <totals>
                <fee>
                    <class>fee/sales_quote_address_total_fee</class>
                </fee>
            </totals>
        </quote>
   </sales>
```

This means whenever the totals are calculated for a quote, it will also call this class.

All collectors are called from the collectTotals() function in the Quote Model.

In our collector class we put in the code

```
<?php class Excellence_Fee_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Fee
```

extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract{
    protected $_code = 'fee';

```
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    parent::collect($address);

    $this->_setAmount(0);
    $this->_setBaseAmount(0);

    $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
    if (!count($items)) {
        return $this; //this makes only address type shipping to come through
    }


    $quote = $address->getQuote();

    if(Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::canApply($address)){ //your business logic
        $exist_amount = $quote->getFeeAmount();
        $fee = Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee();
        $balance = $fee - $exist_amount;
        $address->setFeeAmount($balance);
        $address->setBaseFeeAmount($balance);

        $quote->setFeeAmount($balance);

        $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() + $address->getFeeAmount());
        $address->setBaseGrandTotal($address->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseFeeAmount());
    }
}

public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    $amt = $address->getFeeAmount();
    $address->addTotal(array(
            'code'=>$this->getCode(),
            'title'=>Mage::helper('fee')->__('Fee'),
            'value'=> $amt
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

}
Here we are using two fields fee_amount and base_fee_amount, which contain our fee amount. We will have to see save these two fields to database, so in our module installer file we add this code

```
ALTER TABLE  `".$this->getTable('sales/quote_address')."` ADD  `fee_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `".$this->getTable('sales/quote_address')."` ADD  `base_fee_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
```

Order Page
Till now, all code written has been done only for the quote object. But after order is placed, we need to transfer all information to the order object. As you would have seen above we are using two fields fee_amount and base_fee_amount, we now need to store these two fields in the order table as well. To do all the above we need to do two things. First in the config.xml file add this code inside the global tab,

```
<fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote_address>
        <fee_amount><to_order>*</to_order></fee_amount>
        <base_fee_amount><to_order>*</to_order></base_fee_amount>
        </sales_convert_quote_address>
  </fieldsets>
```

in our module install file

```
ALTER TABLE  `".$this->getTable('sales/order')."` ADD  `fee_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
    ALTER TABLE  `".$this->getTable('sales/order')."` ADD  `base_fee_amount` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL;
```